# Taylor expansion of matrix

Tags: matrices, taylor-expansion, matrix-calculus

I would like to approximate the following matrix using the Taylor expansion.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos(x) &    e^x \\
    e^x  & \sin(x) 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Do I approximate each entry of the matrix separately and then put them back in matrix form?

I cannot find any resources online on how to do this.

Comment: yes, that's pretty much how to do it.